# C++: parsing a 132x65 binary file

Tags: c++, parsing, binary

So here is what i have/have to do. I have a .txt file that has a big picture of 132x72. What i need to do is put that into a c array of hex values.

I need to find a way to grab the first character of the top 8 lines and put them together horizontally so i can then convert them into hex. Then i need to do that 9 times down.

Example:

```
00000
00000
11111
01010
10101
10101
01010
10101
```

That i would need to turn into:

```
00101101
00110010
00101101
00110010
00101101
```

What is the best/simplest way to do this? I honestly do not know where to start.

Comment: I don't understand the transformation.  How does the first relate to the second?

Comment: (1) Is this ASCII art, or an actual image file? (2) Is what you're describing just a Counter-Clockwise rotation of the ASCII art?

Comment: The @wallyk the first column becomes the first row, second col to second row... so on. I guess its ascii art. But i just need to be able to get 8 bit parts of it so that i can convert those to hex values.

Comment: @LiverpoolFTW: why do you need the bits of the ASCII characters? This doesn't appear to be related in any way binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the ones and zeros are **characters** (if it's something binary then you'll need to convert them first) in your .txt file: just read the file line by line into an array. You can then print the array with a stride, i. e. First print characters 0, 8, 16, 24 ... and then 1, 9, 17, ... and so on:

```c
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
        printf("%c", chars[i + j * ROWS]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: This, i guess i didnt explain the question well enough because there was a lot of confusion but this is what i was looking for. Thanks for that.

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Next time you'll know how to formulate the question better ;)

Comment: Just a note: Missed that you used C++, so replace printf and possibly `char*` with `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting format. In any event, read in a line and then add values appropriately to an array. This is what I mean:

Input Line 1: `01101`

would correspond to some array: `image[0][0] = 0, image[1][0] = 1 ...`

This may be best done with `std::vector` using the `push_back()` method.

```
// If you know the image size already
unsigned char image[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS/8]; // 8 bits per byte

std::ifstream file("yourfile.txt", std::ifstream::in);

// Initialize the array to 0 with memset or similar

// Read the whole file
int rows = 0;
int cols = 0;
while(!file.eof) {
  std::string line;

  // Get line by line
  std::getline(file, line);

  // Parse each line (probably better in another function)
  const char* str = line.c_str();
  while(str[rows] != '\0') {
    unsigned val = str[rows] - '0'; // Convert to int
    unsigned shift = 8 - (rows % 8); // 8 bits per byte - this is tricky big-endian or little endian?
    image[rows][cols/8] |= val << shift; // Convert to int val and pack it to proper position
    rows++;
  }

  cols++;
  rows = 0;
}

file.close();
```

The code is untested, but should give you a rough idea on how to read the data in properly. Now you have a properly formatted 2-dimensional array with your values (this is what the shifting was for). From here, you can take these values as `int` values and convert them appropriately (a base 16 conversion is trivial from binary - i.e. each byte has two hexadecimal digits)